# Powershell posh-ssh and cisco

Tags: powershell, ssh, cisco, posh-ssh

I am having some issues getting command to work with `posh-ssh` and Cisco gear.

Commands are pretty simple;

```
New-SSHSession -ComputerName 10.10.101.240 -Port 22
```

Will connect fine, and will give me an ID.

I then try

```
Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionId 0 -Command "show version"
```

but I always get

```
    Exception calling "EndExecute" with "1" argument(s): "An established connection was aborted by the server."
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Posh-SSH\2.0.2\Posh-SSH.psm1:266 char:25
+                         $Output = $_.cmd.EndExecute($_.Async)
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SshConnectionException
```

I have tried different hosts and different PCs.
I can, however, use `$sshsession.write()` and `$sshsession.read()` and I can talk to the switch fine.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I cannot find an original documentation, but you can't use invoke-sshcommand with Cisco gear, you need to use the ShellStream / SSH Stream and write()/read() methods. https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/issues/146 alludes to it

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.. I will just use write and read.